# How to call a onload function in XHTML and in my code there is no body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

How to call  a onload function in XHTML and in my code there is no body tag.I am using Struts in front end.I need to check the check boxes whether its checked during pageload .According to that I have to change the color of checked rows .The checking  method should be in JQuery.
Please let me know if anybody know the answer.

Comment: Are you sure it's XHTML? Because if it really is, having a `body` element would be mandatory

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then why can't you just use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //change color of checked rows here
}
```

Place this code in the head of your html document between script tags. It runs after the document is ready.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //code above goes here
   </script>
</head>
```

I would have just commented but I don't have enough rep so I just answered.

Comment: Is this correct?   $(document).ready(function changeRowBackgroudColor(checkBox) {
       //code for color change
      });

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { changeRowBackgroudColor(checkBox)  }); I would put your function somewhere else (ideally an external script file and then call your function in the document.ready